# How can I place a mask under a modal on my page with AngularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have HTML / AngularJS code that shows a main content window or a modal on my page.

```
<div id="header">
      .
</div>
<div id="main">
   <div id="content" ng-show ..>
      ...
   </div>
   <div id="modal"   ng-show ..>
      .
   </div>
</div>
```

My code is setting ng-show appropriately for when the content or the modal areas are viewed.

This works good but I have problems in that the header is still touchable while a user is on the modal screen.  Is there a way I could put a mask or something to stop the header area being touchable when the modal is being viewed.

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle with it in action?

Comment: you can use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal for better modal control

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura He's obviously not using bootstrap otherwise i'm sure the bootstrap modal would be in use, rather than a custom one.

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura - All the code is working as is just want to mask out the header area. But not quite sure how I place a mask over an area. It's maybe as much of an HTML / CSS question as AngularJs. What I think I will need to do is to add a class to the #header but I am not sure what the class would need to do.

Comment: @Alan Please create jsFiddle, so easily solve your problem and could help you

Comment: Is your modal full screen or a section of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have it setup exactly.

You could add an overlay to the whole screen:

```
 <div class="modal" ng-show="activeModal">
   <div class="modal-content">
     ...
   </div>
 </div>
```

`modal-content` is the main modal. The wrapping parent is the overlay.

Then as long as your modal has a higher z-index than the header, it will overlap the header:

```
.header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;    
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:darkred;
}

.modal {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

If you want the modal to cover only part of the screen, and without a full screen overlay, you can do the same thing, but change the overlay to have no background (so it will still cover the screen, but 'visually', not, and thus, disabling the header from being clickable). You'd also need to have a higher `z-index` for the `modal-content`.

[Demo with full screen overlay and modal](http://jsfiddle.net/msdsLrqL/3/)

[Demo with full screen overlay and small modal](http://jsfiddle.net/yjveyjeu/2/)